# In SQL, in a parent-child relationship, is there any way to make sure that each parent is linked to only one child?

Tags: mysql, sql, parent-child

I have a parent-child relationship and I want to make sure in my database that each parent is linked to only one child.
Here is an example of what I have

```
CREATE TABLE Parents (
       ParentId int NOT NULL,
       ...
       PRIMARY KEY (ParentId)
);

CREATE TABLE Children1 (
       ParentId int NOT NULL,
       ...
       PRIMARY KEY (ParentId),
       CONSTRAINT FK_Parent FOREIGN KEY (ParentId) REFERENCES Parents(ParentId)
);

CREATE TABLE Children2 (
       ParentId int NOT NULL,
       ...
       PRIMARY KEY (ParentId),
       CONSTRAINT FK_Parent FOREIGN KEY (ParentId) REFERENCES Parents(ParentId)
);

CREATE TABLE Children3 (
       ParentId int NOT NULL,
       ...
       PRIMARY KEY (ParentId),
       CONSTRAINT FK_Parent FOREIGN KEY (ParentId) REFERENCES Parents(ParentId)
);

CREATE TABLE Children4 (
       ParentId int NOT NULL,
       ...
       PRIMARY KEY (ParentId),
       CONSTRAINT FK_Parent FOREIGN KEY (ParentId) REFERENCES Parents(ParentId)
);
```

I want to make sure that every Parent has only one Child by verifying the PKs of the Children but I have no idea how to do it or if it's even possible

Answer (score 1):

A parent is an individual , a child is an individual and a child could have many parents so 1 table for parent, 1 for children and a junction table to represent the many parents with a unique key on parent.

```
CREATE TABLE Parents (
       Id int NOT NULL,
       ...
       PRIMARY KEY (ParentId)
);

CREATE TABLE Children (
       Id int NOT NULL,
       ...
       PRIMARY KEY (Id),
);

create table parents_children(
  children_id int,
  parents_id int,
  unique key (parent_id),
  foreign key (children_id) references children(id),
  foreign key (parent_id) references parents(id)
);
```